# Unusual behavior of external interrupts when switching other appliances on or off

Tags: power, interrupts

I am using external interrupt on my microcontroller to interrupt on any level change. When I switch a lamp on an interrupt occurs which is not supposed to because it is not connected to my circuit. How is switching appliances On or Off causing external interrupts?

Scenario:
I have a 5V supply used for microcontroller ATmega16. A port on the micro controls a transistor and the output of the transistor connects to an external interrupts which detects any level change. SO when the port is low the interrupt would detect high and vice versa. here is a diagram to make things simpler. [image]

I just happen to switch the lamp on my desk and saw an interrupt had occurred and then I switched it back off and another interrupt occurred. Is there a reason why this is happening?

Comment: Could you tell us what microcontroller and how things are hooked up(schematic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess since your information is so sparse.  The short answer is you have a crappy power supply or crappy grounding.

### Crappy power supply

The power voltage at the micro needs to be steady.  At the very least, it needs to stay within the min and max voltage operating limits, else all kinds of things can happen, including thinking it got a interrupt.  When you switch on the lamp, it causes a momentary current surge somewhere.  Without knowing what the lamp is hooked up to, I can only guess that it is glitching the power supply.

These kinds of short term glitches are usually dealt with by having capacitance accross the supply in various places.  Power supplies can't react instantly to higher current demand.  There is usually a bulk capacitance at the power supply itself, then smaller distributed capacitors elsewhere, finally ending in bypass caps immediately accross the power and ground connections of individual components.  Make sure all those are properly in place.

### Crappy grounding

Even if the power voltage *accross* the micro is solid when the lamp turns on, there could be common mode bounce.  Good grounding seeks to have one net that varies little in voltage from place to place that is usually called "ground".  This net is then used as the reference voltage by all parts of the circuit.  If this is done properly, then there can't be much common mode bounce in one part of the circuit compared to others.

You could have enough common mode bounce in the local micro ground relative to wherever the external interrupt signal is coming from so that it looks like a valid interrupt signal to the micro.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Olin, The power supply and the lamp are connected to two separate wall sockets. The power supply seems to be fine because everything works fine until today when I discovered switch my lamp On creates an interrupt. I understand crappy grounding but I don't know any way around it.

Comment: @David: Do you have 100nF to 1uF ceramic caps accross all power and ground pins of the micro as close as possible to the micro? Where is the external interrupt signal coming from? The lamp switching on may cause a high dV/dt, which could capacitively couple into your circuit.

Comment: I have 100nF capacitor across the two power and ground pins of the micro. The external interrupt is triggered from one of the general purpose pins on the micro.

Comment: @David: Are you sure you important input pins aren't floating, like whatever could reset the processor?  What about other pins that could be causing a level change interrupt?  I don't know if AVRs have more than one interrupt-on-change pin, but on some PICs you get either none or 4.  If you want just 1 you have to ignore the others in firmware.  In any case, don't leave any input pins floating.  It's bad for a number of reasons.

Comment: I have no input pins floating. The only input pin I am using is the external interrupt. The serial communication works fine and I am using RX and TX interrupts for that too. These two interrupts work fine and even the external pin provided I don't switch ANYTHING on or off during that time.

Comment: Problem solved. I had JTAG still connected to my micro. I took it out and tried switching the lamp many times and the interrupt didn't change its state. And tried connecting the JTAG again and then the interrupt changes state when lamp was switched. Anyway Thanks for your help Olin appreciate it